# disable or remove 'next' button when there aren't anymore records to display PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php page which has records displaying in a table. I have successfully managed to add some sort of pagination to the page however I am confused about how to disable or not show the 'next' button if there aren't anymore records to display. Right now it will just allow the user to keep clicking 'next' and display an empty table. Can anybody help me achieve this?

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  //give the value of the starting row to 0
  $startrow = 0;
//otherwise take the value from the URL
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
        try {

            $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

            $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT * FROM course_details LIMIT $startrow, 5");
            $stmt->execute();
            $courses = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class = "container-fluid">
                <div id = "table_container" style="width:auto; margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6">
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr >
                                        <th class="text-center">
                                            Course Code
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="text-center">
                                            Course Title
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <!-- populating the table with information from mysql database -->
                                    <?php foreach ($courses as $row) {
                                        echo "<tr><td>";
                                        echo $row['course_code'];
                                        echo "</td><td>";
                                        echo $row['course_title'];
                                        echo "</td><td>";
                                        echo "</tr>"; }
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <?PHP

                            echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+5).'" class="pull-right">Next</a>';
                            $prev = $startrow - 5;

                            if ($prev >= 0)
                                echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'">Previous</a>';
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Which looks like this when there are records:

[image: Records Exist]

And this when there aren't any:

[image: No records to display]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the number of displayed records. If it is less than 5 there is certainly no more records to show.

```php
<?php 
   $recordCount = 0;
   foreach ($courses as $row) {
        $recordCount++; 
        echo "<tr><td>";
        ...
   }
?>
```

echo a `"Next"` with no link if `$recordCount` < 5

```php
echo $recordCount == 5
    ? '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+5).'" class="pull-right">Next</a>';
    : '<span class="pull-right">Next</span>';
```

Comment: Thank you. had to make some minor adjustments but using this worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Before echoing the Next button, execute another query for the next record using

```
LIMIT $startrow+5, 1
```

Then

```
if (count($courses) > 0)
  echo next button
```

Comment: would i execute the same query again as shown in my question for the courses? but just replace the limit with the one you've suggested?